# Convert date object to the same time in different timezone and get timestamp of it

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, timestamp, datetime-format

I have a GMT+1 date object `Wed Feb 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`. I want to convert this object to GMT+0 with exactly the same date:

GMT: 1 Feb 2017 00:00:00 GMT;

When I parse my object it returns timestamp which is equal to `Tue, 31 Jan 2017 23:00:00 GMT`.

How to convert my GMT+1 date object to gets timestamp equal to the same date in GMT+0? I tried to use moment.js but I couldn't handle that.

@edit

code with explanation [here](https://jsbin.com/kotadeheyu/1/edit?js,console)

```js
// User chooses 1st Feb 2017, but since components works with GMT +1
const userChoice = new Date(2017, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)
// And backend works with timestamps I parse userChoice
const timestamp = moment(userChoice).valueOf()
// Which gives me timestamp equal to 31st of Dec 2016
console.log(timestamp, moment(timestamp).utc().format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss Z'))
// But I want to have the same date as user chooses, but in a specific (GMT+0) timezone
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Midnight GMT+1 is 11pm GMT+0 though. If you want a specific timestamp, why not just make it yourself?

Comment: Show how you are parsing the "object" (which seems to be a string). What format do you want the timestamp in?

Comment: User chooses date via materia-ui's DatePicker component which gives me UTC (gmt +1) date object. I want the same date (and time) but in GMT (change `1st Feb 2017 00:00:00 GMT+1` to `1st Feb 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0`). I know i could hard code that, but I don't think that's the way, since my UTC changes between GMT +1 and GMT +2.

Comment: @RobG I posted code so it can be more understandable.

Comment: You should post the code here… oh, someone's done that. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out the solution. We will call date object "mod" which gives us `Wed Feb 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100`.

`const mod = new Date(1485903600000)`

Now we will create variable that gives us timestamp of the exact same time (e.g. day, hours, etc.) but in UTC.

`const utc = Date.UTC(mod.getFullYear(), mod.getMonth(), mod.getDate(), mod.getHours(), mod.getMinutes(), mod.getSeconds())`
If we want to check if our timestamp is correct we can simply create new Date with this timestamp and console.log it.

`console.log(1485907200000) // Wed Feb 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 <=> Wed Feb 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000`

Comment: You can simply adjust the original date by the time zone offset so that the UTC values are the same as the original local values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Looking at your code:

```
// User chooses 1st Feb 2017, but since components works with GMT +1
const userChoice = new Date(2017, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)
```

That creates a Date object equivalent to midnight at the start of 1 February 2017 in the host system time zone.

```
// And backend works with timestamps I parse userChoice
const timestamp = moment(userChoice).valueOf()
```

You aren't "parsing" *userChoice*, it's a Date object. You're getting the time value, which is an offset in milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z and is equivalent to `userChoice.getTIme()`.

```
// Which gives me timestamp equal to 31st of Dec 2016
console.log(timestamp, moment(timestamp).utc().format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss Z'))
```

No it doesn't. The original date is for 1 Feb, it can only be shifted by a maximum of one day either way by time zones. For hosts set to a timezone west of Greenwich, the timezone adjustment when the Date is created will mean the UTC date is 1 Feb, but for hosts to the east, the UTC date will be 31 Jan.

```
// But I want to have the same date as user chooses, but in a specific (GMT+0) timezone
```

To create a Date for a specific UTC date, then use UTC methods. Alternatively, if you have a Date object, you can adjust it by the host offset:

```js
// Create date for 1 Feb, 2017 based on host offset
var d = new Date(2017, 1, 1);

// Create UTC Date for same date
var u = new Date(Date.UTC(2017,1,1));

console.log('Local: ' + d.toISOString());
console.log('UTC  : ' + u.toISOString());

// Adjust d for timezone offset
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset())
console.log('Adjusted: ' + d.toISOString());
```

If that doesn't help, please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

A **date** object can not be converted to different time-zone as it only keeps the number of milliseconds that passed since Jan 1, 1970 and it is the same for all places around the world.

However the **date** object may be interpreted in different time zone (also known as a local time) based on the time-zone offset value.

You do not need to even know the fixed value of the time-zone offset;
let the computer take care of it for you, as it will also include summer daylight saving time changes between different places and at the right time.
All you need to know is the time-zone description that could be looked-up at [iana.org](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) website.

```js
let now = new Date(),
    current = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone,
    zones = [current , 'Europe/London', 'Asia/Tokyo'];

zones.forEach((z)=>{
  console.log("Time in "+ z + " is " +
               now.toLocaleString("en-ES",{timeZone: z}))
});
```